# SQL combine based on common row value

Tags: sql-server, merge, key, sql-server-2017

I am attempting to migrate from one help desk software to another, part of that is migrating our ticket history database over, which I exported to a excel spreadsheet and then imported into a SQL Server database.

The current format of the table is as follows:

Column headers:

```
Description: Initial ticket text  
ticketnum: Ticket number  
subject: Ticket subject header  
value: ticket comment
```

In case it's needed:

```
Description: nvarchar(max)  
ticketnum: float  
subject: nvarchar(max)  
value: nvarchar(max)
```

Edit: Example data as asked:

```
Description            TicketNum     Subject                       Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Our computer exploded   10020        CPU Explosion        Our computer exploded
Our computer exploded   10020        CPU Explosion        The computer is a dell
Virus Found             10021        Virus                We need help with a virus
```

I'd want that to become:

```
Description            TicketNum     Subject              Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Our computer exploded   10020        CPU Explosion        Our computer exploded; The computer is a dell
Virus Found             10021        Virus                We need help with a virus
```

Every row is a new entry into a ticket, so the value field is always unique, while the description and value stay the same for each ticket number. So I am looking to merge the rows based on the ticket number field, keep/merge ALL the data of the value fields and only keep one value of both the subject and description fields. I have seen a number of questions that come close to my scenario, but none match and sadly I know very little about SQL, and not enough to extrapolate based on what I've seen to figure this out solo.

Thank you so much in advance.

Edit 2: Revised code, runs but doesn't merge, produces an empty table:

```
declare @tmpTable table ([Description] nvarchar(max), niceid float, 
[Subject] nvarchar(max), [Value] nvarchar(max))

SELECT * INTO tmpTable FROM sheetnew$

declare @newTable table ([Description] nvarchar(max), niceid float, 
[Subject] nvarchar(max), [Value] nvarchar(max))


insert into @newTable
select distinct 
    x.[Description]
    ,x.niceID
    ,x.[Subject]
   ,[Value] = stuff((
          select '; ' + y.[Value]
          from @tmptable y
          where x.niceid = y.niceid
          for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from @tmptable x
```

Comment: Don't use Float for ticketnumber use an bigint or even int. Its highly unlike that you will ever issue over a billion tickets. If you do have over a billion tickets at company find another job.

Comment: Rather than telling you how to do it, I would suggest taking a look at MSSQL Documentation and getting familiar with SQL. Check out the Select Statement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-examples-transact-sql) and various things you can do it such as Distinct (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

Comment: got some sample data? Regardless, for the new table, make `ticketnum int identity(1,1)` and let SQL Server handle the increments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using `STUFF`

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

declare @table table ([Description] varchar(64), TicketNum int, [Subject] varchar(64), [Value] varchar(4000))
insert into @table
values
('Our computer exploded',10020,'CPU Explosion','Our computer exploded'),
('Our computer exploded',10020,'CPU Explosion','The computer is a dell'),
('Virus Found',10021,'Virus','We need help with a virus')





declare @newTable table ([Description] varchar(64), TicketNum int, [Subject] varchar(64), [Value] varchar(4000))
insert into @newTable
select distinct 
    x.[Description]
    ,x.TicketNum
    ,x.[Subject]
    ,[Value] = stuff((
          select '; ' + y.[Value]
          from @table y
          where x.TicketNum = y.TicketNum
          for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from @table x


select * from @newTable
```

Comment: I get what you are doing to a degree, however when I try to reference my table (sheetnew$) your query no longer works: I'll put code in main question @scsimon

Comment: My answer works perfectly. However in your edit you forgot an @ sign on your select into statement. You haven’t elaborated on what error you get and I don’t know what sheetnew$ is.....

Comment: Your answer does work perfectly, however when instead of using the table you made using my test data I instead reference tmpTable, which is a table made of my actual ticket information, (that's what sheenew$ is, 100k rows of ticket data in the same format as the example data I gave) it produces an empty table. https://i.imgur.com/FaYgCVe.jpg @scsimon

Comment: @evangelism a temp table is preceded by a # not proceeded by a $. In your code, you have forgotten an @ on your table *variable* which is different from a temp table. You can't do a `SELECT INTO` on a table variable. You must **insert** the data with an insert command. `INSERT INTO @tmpTable SELECT * FROM sheetnew$`. However, I still don't know what `sheetnew$` is. Regardless, this is outside the scope of the original question and you should open a new one if you are still having trouble. Just a heads up, you have created an actual table called `tmpTable` in your database...